# Host database on web server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have desktop application with a SQL Server database hosted on local network. Now my customer wants to host database somewhere on the web, so employees can access it from anywhere using desktop apps not only from office.

And I'm wondering if I can move database to web hosting and connect to it transparently as if it was in local network? I'm sorry for being noob, I haven't coded for web yet...

How easy is that move for a SQL Server database to web hosting?

Answer (score 6):

Not a great idea, exposing a database directly to clients across the web, for security reasons if nothing else.

This can be achieved using a web API - a programming interface on the web that the clients connect to and which itself uses a database behind the scenes.

Using such an API gives you control over what the clients do, which ones are allowed to connect, add an authentication and authorization layer and more.

The Microsoft [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) is made for just such things.